# How to filter based on value in json using JQ

Tags: jq

```
{    "amazon": {

                "items": [
                  {
                    "name": "harry potter",
                    "state": "sold"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "adidas shoes",
                    "state": "in inventory"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "watch",
                    "state": "returned"
                  },
                 ]
    }

}
```

I want to write jq json parsing tool to modify "name:harry potter" from state "sold" to "returned"

I want to modify this in a shell script ( .sh ) file.

Comment: make string json to object then access it by index/key and change value and return it to string json again

Comment: I am writing in shell script, and i am not sure of how to make it an object,

Comment: The input shown is not valid JSON.  Please fix it.

Comment: @peak fixed now you may check

Comment: check it.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140030/replacing-values-in-json-file-with-jq

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is valid JSON, the following filter will perform the edit conditionally as specified:

```
.amazon.items
|= map(if .name == "harry potter" and .state == "sold"
       then .state = "returned" else . end)
```

Or rather, invoking jq with this filter will emit the updated JSON.

You might want to use `sponge` to overwrite the original file once you're sure that's really what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Another `jq` filter using `select` function:

```
jq '.amazon.items |= map(select(.name=="harry potter").state="returned")' file
```